# Вопрос по переводу чисел между системами счисления

Tags: математика, информатика

Почему `из десятичной в любую` систему (что в двоичную, что в шестнадцатеричную) число переводится методом деления, а `из любой в десятичную` - другим методом? Чем так обособлена именно десятичная система? Ведь, с точки зрения математики она ничем не должна отличаться от тех же двоичной и шестнадцатеричной кроме алфавита - набора символов. Мне всегда казалось, что `из большей в меньшую` переводим методом деления, а `из меньшей в большую` - другим методом.

Comment: Это каким еще другим? Естественно, что все системы счисления с натуральным основанием не менее 2 :) одинаковы.

Comment: @Harry, из двоичной в десятичную переводим иным методом, когда над каждым символом числа пишется степень двойки (0, 1, 2), и результирующие числа, получаемые умножением этой степени на соответствующий ей символ, складываются.

Comment: Ну и что дальше? Вы получаете число, которое потом нужно раскладывать на десятки, сотни и т.д. Более просто работает только пересчет между системами счисления, где основания - разные степени одного числа, типа из двоичной в шестнадцатеричную - группируем по 4 бита...

Comment: В общем случае из записи сначала собирается численное значение, которое потом переводится в другую запись. То, что языки программирования имеют встроенное средство вывода числа в десятичной записи, не означает, что такое преобразование не выполняется :)

Comment: @nup А кто вам мешает в десятичной системе вычитать из числа степени двойки начиная со старшей и двочное представление этих степеней складывать. и никакого деления. И я уже молчу про double dabble алгоритм ... способов прилично

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю ваш вопрос, то, скорее всего, у вас когнитивный диссонанс :) из-за того, что вы выполняете перевод из двоичной в десятичную - ну, типа, `110101 = 1 + 4 + 16 + 32 = 53`, и забываете о том, что вы *уже работаете в десятичной записи*. И на этом ваше преобразование завершено.

Давайте иначе - через, ну, скажем, семеричную. Тогда
`110101 = 1 + 4 + 22 + 44 = 104`

Если бы вы работали в семеричной системе счисления, вы бы это `104` считали ответом и больше ничего не делали. Разве что задали бы здесь вопрос - и чем же семеричная система счисления такая выдающаяся? :)

А теперь нужно `104` перевести в десятичную... Делим `104` на `13` (`10` в семеричной), получаем `5`, и в остатке `3`, итого записываем в десятичной `53`...

Это ответ на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Да, спасибо, в какой-то степени вопрос прояснился.

Answer (score 1):

Методы одинаковые и ничем не отличаются.

```
12345 dec = 30071 oct

12345 divrem 8 = 1543 1
 1543 divrem 8 =  192 7
  192 divrem 8 =   24 0
   24 divrem 8 =    3 0
    3 divrem 8 =    0 3

0o30071 divrem 10 = 0o2322 5
 0o2322 divrem 10 =  0o173 4
  0o173 divrem 10 =   0o14 3
   0o14 divrem 10 =    0o1 2
    0o1 divrem 10 =    0o0 1
```

Десятичная обусловлена исторически 10 пальцами на руках.

А вообще, можно [почитать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988) :)